# Empty 'folder' not removed in GCS

Tags: python, rest, google-cloud-storage

When I delete through the `Console` all files from a "folder" in a `bucket`, that folder is gone too since there is no such thing as directories - the whole path after the `bucket` is the key.

However when I move (`copy` & `delete` method) programmatically these files through `REST API`, the folder remains, empty. I must therefore write additional logic to check for these and remove explicitly.

Isn't that a bug in the `REST API` handling ? I had expected the same behavior regardless of the method used.

Comment: This answer talks about similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/46475804/1578466

Comment: @YogeshPatil thanks for the reference. Did some further testing and answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that you can safely remove all object ending with `/` if you don't need them once empty. "Content" will not be deleted.

If you are using `Google Console`, you must create a folder before uploading to it. That folder is therefore an explicit object that will remain even if empty. Same behavior apparently when uploading with tools like `Cyberduck`.

But if you upload the file using REST API and its full path i.e. `bucket/folder/file`, the folder is implicit *visually* but it's not getting created as such. So when removing the file, there is no folder left behind since it wasn't there in the first place.

Since the expected behavior for my use case is to auto-remove empty folders, I just have a pre-processing routine that deletes all blobs ending with `/`